# Jquery countdown but if page refresh/F5 still keep timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for jquery plugin countdown, But if page refreshed still keep conter. I'm making application for questionnaire which I want to show countdown timer until 60 minutes. My application now if user login to start answer questions, He answer one by one question, which the question is one question per page. So if next question page will refresh. So now if user want to answer next question countdown timer will reset to default.
Now I'm using jquery plugin this http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

With code:

```
   $(function () {
        var d = new Date();
        d = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes()+59, 59);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: d, format: 'MS'});
    });
```

So my question, is there plugin countdown timer if page refreshed whitout reset timer to default.

Thanks.

Comment: you can save your counter in a cookie. ( or db but cookie is better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by saving the deadline in a cookie, and fetch the value from that cookie on each request. Your code will be a little more complicated, but it'll do the job. You'll need the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), and you might want to [read up on how to use it](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

[This is what I come up with](http://jsfiddle.net/t9BCM/2/). You can change the value of `withCookie` to see the difference between saving and not saving the deadline between requests (click "run" instead of reloading - in practice, it'll do the same thing). Since I couldn't find a CDN that hosted the countdown plugin you're using, I just printed the deadline - but since what you wanted was to make sure that the deadline remains fixed, the only thing you need to do now is to generate the deadline date variable `d`as in the jsFiddle (except the seconds), and then call

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: d, format: 'MS'});
```

Comment: Hello. OK I will test with cookie. Thanks.

Comment: I has been solved with callback function and store minute and second to mysql, because if I use cookie, How if user use other computer to login. My question, Is it will need big memory with always update to database mysql every one second? Thanks

Comment: @LorenRamly: If you're using that approach, just save the time when the deadline expires. On each pageload, you then load the deadline from the database and set a counter to the expiry date. There's no need to update the database every second - you only read from it on pageload, and you only write to it whenever you need to change the deadline.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" (by ticking the little check under the vote count) if this solved your problem. Also, make sure you upvote all the answers that helped you =)

Comment: @LorenRamly: Hi, I am having similar task to achieve. Can you please give some clue how you achieved it using callback? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store initial date in `localStorage` and try to restore it from there once page is refreshed. After the question is answered you can delete date from `localStorage`

```
$(function () {
  var d = localStorage.getItem('date');
  if(!d) {
    d = (new Date()).getTime() + 3599000;
    localStorage.setItem('date', d);
  } else {
    d = parseInt(d);
  }
  $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(d), format: 'MS'});
});

function goNext() {
  localStorage.removeItem('date');
  // Go to next question
  ...
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/oxovih/2/edit

Comment: @LorenRamly I have updated the example, now it works. You can check it on JSBin. You also have an error in your deadline computation algorithm, so I fixed it a bit :)